# git ssh alias not working unless I add the key to ssh-agent (OSX)

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent

I added a ssh alias to use a different key-pair for a certain domain. The key does not have a passphrase.  I had followed the directions at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html and at the end added the ssh key with ssh-add.

I later rebooted and the key wasn't working any more - a git fetch from the console in the repo using the alias failed with a permission error.  I looked at ssh-add -l and noticed that the key wasn't there anymore.  I looked at [ssh-add is not persistent between reboots](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140075/108129) to understand how to fix this - but it seemed from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140107/108129 that if I don't have a passphrase, I shouldn't need to.

Is there something I can do to not require to add the key to the ssh-agent - or an easy way to add it permanently?

**Update:** my .ssh/config is:

```
VisualHostKey=yes
Host myproject
  HostName bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myproject
Host *
  User yehosef
```

Comment: What exactly did you set up? Good start is to [know what the `ssh-agent` is and how does it work and why you can't add it permanently](http://superuser.com/questions/1152833/save-identities-added-by-ssh-add-so-they-persist/1152861#1152861).

Comment: in my .ssh/config I set a host alias to use a certain IdentityFile for a certain domain.  So in git instead of referring to the origin as `git@bitbucket.com:<user>/<repo>` I use `git@<alias>:<user>/<repo>` when go to the repo and do a (eg) `git fetch`, I have a permission issue.  If I type `ssh-add <other IdentityFile>` then the `git fetch` works.  I had understood from the link I included that if I don't have a passphrase, which I don't, I shouldn't need  ssh-agent.  Yet it seems I do.

Comment: Please, update the question with these details and the content of your `.ssh/config`.