# How to avoid using 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa' for every push to a github repo?

Tags: ssh, git, gitlab

I have to repeatedly enter the following terminal commands in order to be able to push to a remote github repository. If I push to github, and then code some more for the next few hours before pushing again, I have to enter the commands:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Otherwise I get the following error messages:

> >> git push origin master
>
> sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
>   Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

What do I have to do so that I will no longer need to keep using ssh-add in order to be able to push? I would have thought that using ssh-add once would have fixed the issue but it seems that isn't the case!

Comment: Hmm, related if not dup: [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/132065/170373) & [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299138/170373), perhaps even [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140075/ssh-add-is-not-persistent-between-reboots)

Comment: I would rather start with "what are you trying to achieve" and "why do you do what you do?". What is your `ssh-agent` before you run a new one? What does `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` print before starting the agent? In what format is your `id_rsa` key?

Answer (score 5):

below is based on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41145954/8740349):

In order to not have to refill in your password even after a restart, add the following to your ssh configuration file (which is commonly located at `~/.ssh/config`, or on `Windows` at `%UserProfile%/.ssh/config`)

```
Host *
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your ssh key file - `id_rsa` to the directory ~/.ssh/

Use copy or move to place it there rather than the ssh-add

This is the **private** file that start with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If you don't have a private key file, maybe the issue is that your actually need to generate them

- Open a terminal on your local computer and enter the following: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"` ...
- Just press  to accept the default location and file name. ...
  Enter, and re-enter, a passphrase when prompted. ...
- You're done!

These steps are from https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html

Comment: The OP mentions `~/.ssh/id_rsa` — what makes you think it's missing or invalid?

Comment: Because that is within the context of the `ssh-add` command.  Maybe there's an issue with that is what I thought.

Comment: When the OP does that, the push works, which suggests the `ssh-add` command worked too. It sounds more like the SSH agent is dying for some reason (or no longer responding on its socket, which happens with GNOME’s keyring daemon on my system).

Comment: Sure @StephenKitt you are correct. My answer is somewhat like a comment, but obviously far too long.  It's meant more for the OP to try it as investigative and maybe it'll work or maybe it'll show an error.  Maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried suggestions like changing file/directory permissions and ssh-add, a gitlab documentation helped me solve a similar issue.

Have you tried ed25519 instead of rsa?

It is important to check if the encryption type used by your public key is supported by the server you are connecting to. For example, a gitlab server I was trying to did not support the type of keys usually stored in `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub`

Instead, it required ed25519 or rsa encrypted keys. For ed25519, to generate a new key, one can use : `$ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "email@example.com"`

Then, `$ssh -T user@server` should offer a good check if this key is accepted and a connection can be established.